# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable - Accepts as list in one case but as an int in another

Tags: python, list, typeerror

This code generates the error on the title.

```
    s = list()    
    def add():
        global s
        s.append(int(e.get()))
        e.delete(0,END)
        print(sum(s))
```

But this code :

```
    s = list()
    def add():
        global s
        s.append(int(e.get()))
        e.delete(0,END)
        print(s)
```

gives the ouput

```
[123]
[123, 852]
[123, 852, 95]
[123, 852, 95, 0]
[123, 852, 95, 0, 751]
[123, 852, 95, 0, 751, 95]
```

When 123,852,95,0,751,95 are entered by the user.
Why does sum() treats the same variable differently.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to pass a list to sum() function but it was giving the error
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

This was a Jupyter issue and after restarting the kernel it started to work fine.

So if you are using Jupyter or something like it. Try restarting the kernel. It can help.